How to access set value in terraform
I cannot access terraform set members by indexing
This gives me an error:
variable "set" {
  type = set(string)
  default = ["./someFile2.txt", "Hello World Again!"]
}

output "set" {
  value = var.set[1]
}

I suspect we cannot access members by indexing them, but only by iteration, can you please confirm this? and maybe give some example for it.

Informations on the internet are kinda useless on this topic: https://www.devopsschool.com/blog/terraform-tutorials-set-data-type-and-example/
The official documentation is not better either:  https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/expressions/types#set

Update:

error message: Elements of a set are identified only by their value and don't have any separate index or key to select with, so it's only possible to perform operations across all elements of the │ set.

Well this sort of confirms my suspicion, but then how to use it, or is it common to use this data type (at 1st look this brings much more headaches than solutions)

What do you want to achieve with the variable? Data sources are useful, but it's unclear how and where you want to use the set.

I don't have any specific use case, it's for education purposes, I'd like to understand what problems are solved with sets

By definition a set is unordered and members cannot be accessed individually. You would need a list instead:
variable "list" {
  type = list(string)
  default = ["./someFile2.txt", "Hello World Again!"]
}

output "list" {
  value = var.set[1]
}

If at some point you need to coerce the type back to a set for some reason then the toset function would achieve that.

Ah..., that's what I missed, sets are unordered!
